# Possible Test Scenarios for a Kafka Consumer that Pushes Records to the S3 After Processing

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, reactive-programming

I have a `Kafka` consumer that:

1. Consumes records from `Kafka`.
2. Processes each one of them in parallel by calling three down-stream services.
3. Pushes a final processed documents (corresponding to each record) into the `S3`.

Some additional info:

1. I am using `commitAsync(..)`;
2. I am using `Spring Reactor`.

Apart from the happy case, what should be the possible scenarios that I should cover? Considering that I am processing an `X` amount of messages per `poll(..)` and processing and committing them all in parallel? I want my entire program to be tested as harshly as possible.

Comment: Side note : the better pattern to follow here is to write your processed documents to a Kafka topic, and then use Kafka Connect to stream them to S3.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt interesting. How is this better than my pattern though?

Comment: Because you decouple your processing from your storage. If S3 is unavailable/the network's broken/<other fault condition> then with this pattern your processing doesn't block or have to worry about handling exceptions. It just writes back to Kafka. Kafka Connect handles failures, restarts, etc for you. Separation of responsibilities.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt excellent excellent. Thanks.